# How do I include output parameters in a function with Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to include output parameters in a function with TypeScript?
Something like `Func1(string val1, int out k1, int out k2)` in C#.

Answer (score 36):

Not currently.

You can return an object that can contain more than one property.

```
return { k1: 5, k2: 99 };
```

You can combine this with destructuring so the intermediate object becomes invisible...

```
function myFunction() {
    return { k1: 5, k2: 99 };
}

const { k1, k2 } = myFunction();

console.log(k1);
console.log(k2);
```

You could also achieve the same with a tuple, but this is pretty readable.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another way.
Define a callback function which will include your out parameters :

```
function Func1(val1: string, out: (k1: number, k2: number) => void): void {
    out(1, 2);
}
```

Example on how to use it:

```
function anotherFunction(): void {

    let k1: number;
    let k2: number;

    Func1("something", (v1, v2) => {
        k1 = v1;
        k2 = v2;
    });

    console.log(k1); // output: 1
    console.log(k2); // output: 2
}
```

I find it mostly useful for stuff like this:

```
const keys: string[] = [];
const values: number[] = [];

function tryGet(key: string, out: (value: number) => void): void {
    const index = keys.indexOf(key);
    if (index >= 0) {
        out(values[index]);
    }
}

function test(): void {

    const key = "myValue";

    tryGet(key, (value) => {
        console.log(`Key '${key}' exist with value ${value}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Typescript passes all parameters with "call by value". But if the parameter is a reference this behaves similarly to "call by reference" most of the time. You can write wrapper classes for primitive types. Here's some code:

```
var func=function(param:Str){
    param.str="modified";
}
class Str{
    str:string="unmodified";
}
var test:Str=new Str();
alert(test.str); //alerts "unmodified"
func(test);
alert(test.str); //alerts "modified"
```

You need to be careful, though:

```
var func=function(param:Str){
    param=new Str("modified");
}
class Str{
    str:string;
    constructor(param:string){
        this.str=param;
    }
}

var test:Str=new Str("unmodified");
alert(test.str); //alerts "unmodified"
func(test);
alert(test.str); //alerts "unmodified"
```

The function parameter is passed "call by value". Therefore inside the function body you're working with a copy of a reference. This reference points to the same object as the reference that you passed as a parameter, so you can access its members and modify them. But if you assign a new object to the reference all further changes are applied to this new object. Therefore the code above prints unmodified twice. I think C# works this way, too.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you just return an object with multiple properties, one of which contains your function. Something like this:

```
var foo = function (val1 : string){
    // do something

    return {
        k1: 22,
        k2: 33
    };
}
```

You could also make it implement an interface, so you know what to expect as the returned object.

```
interface IFoo {
    (val1: string): INumbers;
}
interface INumbers {
    k1 : number;
    k2 : number;
}

var foo : IFoo = (val1 : string){
    // do something

    return {
        k1: 22,
        k2: 33
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really, really want to have an output parameter, even though you could return an object or an array (as a makeshift tuple object), look at foo and the call site of foo...

```
function p(s) {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s));
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('BR'));
}
function foo(output: any): void {
  output.uno = 1;
  output.dos = 2;
}
var o: any = {};
function foo(o);
p(o.uno + " " + o.dos);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mantain C# like syntax you can use:

```
function func(val1, k1, k2)
{
    k1.v = 7;
    k2.v = 9;
    return "";
}
```

and to call it

```
func("", {}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the parameter is undefined and you need to instantiate it inside a method. In that cases you can use "lambda functions" or "arrow functions" and simulate the output parameter with this:

example:

```
class classA
{
   propertyA : number;
   constructor(value: number){
        propertyA = number;
   }
}

class classB {

    // ...

    exampleMethod(){
       let classAInstance: classA;
       this.sumValueMethod((p) => classAInstance = p, 10);

       if(classAInstance != undefined)
           alert("Yeah"); 
    }

    sumValueMethod(paramA:(p: classA) => any, paramB: number){

       let variableA: classA = new classA(0);
       variableA.propertyA += paramB;

       paramA(variableA);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still not aware of output parameters in Typescript in 2023.

I want to add that usually it is more elegant to use a method or destructuring of a return value into components.

Assume, we have

```
function foo(out x, out y, z) {
    x = z.x
    y = z.y
}
```

Often, the output parameters are related to the operation or to each other and it makes sense to group and encapsulate them inside an object.

```
class Foo {
    var x; var y;
    foo(z) {
        x = z.x
        y = z.y
    }
}
```

But beware that you don't forget to `bind` your functions passed as callbacks.

```
function foo(z) {
    return [z.x, z.y]
}
```

So that you can use

```
[x, y] = foo(z)
```

These two methods basically are equivalent in expression to using output parameters. It might be less convenient if you want to apply output parameters as arguments. In this case, a lambda expression or method definition is required.

Cheers!