# Out and ref in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Typescript: How to pass function parameters by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115278/typescript-how-to-pass-function-parameters-by-reference)

I wonder if there are `out`- and `ref`-like keywords in `TypeScript`? If not, how to emulate them?

Comment: E.g. in `C#` they work like pointers in `C++`, when u pass an object into the method and modify it inside, it will change globally (it's not a local copy). And the difference between `out` and `ref` is that one of them need to be initialized before passing it into the method.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Yes, it's a duplicate, my apologies. Didn't find it earlier. But it isn't solved as well.

Comment: I stand by my answer on the duplicate - you can pass back an object that contains many values, which is neater than accepting out and ref parameters.

Comment: I agree with @SteveFenton, just pass back an object. TypeScript is not intended to be a new language that has every feature from eveyr language. Its built on JavaScript, so it has to work with what JavaScript has. Otherwise, you have CoffeeScript or Dart (which are fine choices, but they are a different animal).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will do this in that way. It's a pretty good answer. Have a good day guys!

Comment: You can also send in objects for all the out parameters which their v gets to. ref1.v = 3;return; and to call it var obj = {}; functionname(obj);console.log(obj.v);